# How to update CustomListView item in Android using Model where the model data is downloaded from internet?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-asynctask

I have a CustomListView in my android app. Each item consists of two pieces of text which are to be retrieved from an online SQL database. I'm using a Model class called ListModel and a custom adapter called CustomAdapter. I'm using an Asynctask to download the model data from the internet. But the problem is that, adding of a ListModel object to my ArrayList is not working when I do it in the onPostExecute method of my Asynctask. So, the listview is not getting updated. How do I display the Model items on my Custom List as soon as they get downloaded? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problems occures when adapter not properly notify after data downloaded. Notify your adapter in postExecute by notifyDataSetChanged () method

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is because [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) isn't called on the arrayadapter. (but stacktraces/your code would be helpful)

---

In addition, this is a prime use of an in-memory SQLite database (if you plan on doing any custom queries)

Or a full on-disk SQLite DB if you want to cache data.

(Adding a content provider(by just surrounding the SqliteDB) would also be nice if you want to abstract away some more and provide observers, etc. )